# PHP basic write error, not getting any result

Tags: php, python, html, raspberry-pi

Just wondering what is going wrong here, have been scratching my head for way too long on this. This is a script being called by another php script and it works correctly until the last bit where it is supposed to write **0.0** to the file. Both -**1 and 1** are written to the file but not the **0.0**. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The output file is just blank. I disabled the last bit and I see **-1 and 1** perfectly, but when I enable the **0** part nothing is there in he file.

Also are these values integers or characters? I am asking this since another program is going to be reading the newfile.txt and taking the data out.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($_POST['leftb'])
{ echo "Left is pressed";
    $txt = "-1 \n";}


else if ($_POST['rightb'])
{ echo "Right is pressed";
    $txt = "1 \n";}


fwrite($myfile, $txt);                                              // Write either -1 or 1 to the file
fclose($myfile);                                                    // Close the file



sleep(2);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); // Open It again
$txt = "0.0 \n";
write($myfile, $txt);                                              // Write 0 to the file

fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: I think you forgot 'f' in front of write, it's should be fwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistyping

Change like this. 
write($myfile, $txt) => fwrite($myfile, $txt)

Everything works good.

at the beginning of code

Add two line.

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

This will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot! :D